# Selecting one object from IEnumerable by clicking on a button

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm creating a tool for editing/disabling Active Directory user accounts. I will search for a username and it will come up with all matches ("jsm" will come up with a table with "John Smith", "James Smoth", and "Jack Smuth"). Beside the user names are buttons "Edit" and "Disable". When the I click "Edit" or "Disable", a bootstrap modal will appear with textboxes containing the account properties such as SamAccountName and DisplayName inside of form inputs.

Because there could be multiple results, I'm passing in an IEnumerable into the view, then foreach through the @Model to put the data into the table. My next step is trying to pass in just that specific User object into the modal. So if the I click on the Edit button beside John Smith, I want his User object to populate the modal.

My first thought is doing a variable of User I can pass the User object from the foreach loop into then use that object in the modal, but I'm not sure how to go about doing that. Can/should I keep this inside the razor view or should I be passing this data into the controller then back out?

Controller:

```
namespace ADM.Controllers
{
    public class ManagementController : Controller
    {
        public new IActionResult User()
        {
            var user = new List<User>();
            return View(user);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public new IActionResult User(string username)
        {
            var user = new User();
            var result = user.Get(username);

            return View(result);
        }

        public IActionResult Group()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

User.cshtml:

```
@model IEnumerable<User>

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "User Management";
    var count = 1;
}

<div class="container col-6">
    <div class="card card-square">
        <div class="card-body">
            <form asp-controller="Management" asp-action="User">
                <div class="form-row form-inline">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control col-10" name="username" placeholder="Username" />
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<br />
@if (Model.Any())
{
    <div class="small">
        <table class="table table-hover table-sm">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col"></th>
                    <th scope="col">Display Name</th>
                    <th scope="col">Description</th>
                    <th scope="col">SamAccountName</th>
                    <th scope="col"></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (var user in Model)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row">@(count++)</th>
                        <td>@user.DisplayName</td>
                        <td>@user.Description</td>
                        <td>@user.SamAccountName</td>
                        <td>
                            <button id="userEditBtn" class="btn btn-sm btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#userEditModal">Edit</button>
                            <button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#userDisableModal">Disable</button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: They way you describe using the object in the modal makes me think that you expect razor view code to be executed client side. Is this correct?

Comment: I didn't think it would be, but my thought process might be wrong. I'm still fumbling through this, trying to build a real-world tool as training.

Once the data is populated in the Modal, I was thinking sending the data/object back into the controller for processing (updating fields/disabling, etc). I haven't gotten to that stage yet. Is that the correct path/process?

Comment: I think @Jasen answer explain all the options you have. To me, your process seems correct. I asked because the changes needed in the razor view are almost trivial. Most of the changes will be in the controller and in the client Javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's more than one way to do this.

If there isn't a lot of User fields, you can store the properties in the DOM for each User button

```
@foreach(var user in Model)
{
    <button class="btnEdit" data-username="@user.Username">Edit</button>
}
```

In your JavaScript button handler you extract the data to populate a form submission or make an AJAX request.

```
$(".btnEdit").on("click", function(e) {
    var form = $("#myform");
    var username = $(this).data("username");

    // populate a form        
    $("input[name='username']").val(username);
    form.submit();
});
```

Another way is to make a AJAX call for the user you want to edit to obtain more data than what you first loaded with the initial collection. Then use the second call to populate the edit form. One quick way is to just load a html partial.

```
$(".btnEdit").on("click", function(e) {
    var username = $(this).data("username");
    var action = $(this).data("action");  // EditDetailsForm

    $.ajax({
        url: action,
        method: "get",
        data: { username = username }
    })
    .then(function(partialView) {
        $("#editForm").html(partialView);
    });
});
```

And the action

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult EditDetailsForm(string username)
{
    var user = GetUser(username);
    return PartialView("_editForm", user);
}
```

Returns a partial view _editForm.cshtml

```
@Model User
<form ...>
  ...
</form>
```

Which you just drop into your modal.

Comment: With consideration for performance, would it be better to have the controller handle this? I'm thinking scale and what if they search for ~1000 users.

My thought process being maybe a partial search when the username is searched for initially (expecting/knowing multiple matches), then when the edit/disable buttons are clicked do a another bigger LDAP query to pull the necessary information based on that exact ID?

Comment: Well then, fetch and load the details when you need it.